# Java: passing string of an object to another object

Tags: java, string, inheritance, null, super

### My post has been closed because of duplication of another question that doesn't really resolve my question so i'm posting it again. because its not about comparing strings its about passing a string of an object to another objects.

I was trying to practise inheritence on Java by writing a code that consist of Parent class that is called **Person** that has two child classes of **SuperPerson** and **Civil**, and the **SuperPerson** class that has two child classes called **Hero** and **Villian**.
I was trying to implement a method called ***Protect*** which is used only by the **Hero** class that can only works on the **Civil** class as a target.
So, the main issue here when i run the code, it doesn't show the protector name in the case of a different hero trying to protect a civil who's already under another hero's protection and in the case of a villian trying to attack a civil who's under hero's protection.

The main method:

```
Hero h1 = new Hero("Spiderman", 25,"Male", "Web");
Hero h2 = new Hero("Batman", 35, "Male","Wealth");
SuperPerson v1 = new Villian("Goblin", 47,"Male", "Goblin Power");
Person c3 = new Civil("Mary", 24,"Female");
h1.protect(c3); //First Hero object protecting the Civil object
h2.protect(c3);//Different Hero object trying to protect the same Civil object
v1.attack(c3);//Villian attacking civil under protection
```

The output:

```
Mary is under Spiderman's proction.
Mary is already under null's protection //Bug here
The target is under null's protection //Bug here
```

The  (Person) parent class:

```
public class Person {
    boolean protection;
}
```

The (SuperPerson) parent class:

```
public class SuperPerson extends Person {
    String protector;
}
```

The first child (Hero) class that has the protect method:

```
public class Hero extends SuperPerson {
    void protect(Person target) {
        if(target.type.equals("Super Villian")) {
            System.out.println("You can not protect a villian!");
        }
        else {
            if(target.health != 0) {
                if(target.protection == false) {//to protect
                    target.protection = true;
                    this.protector = this.name;
                    System.out.println(target.name + " is under " + this.protector + "'s proction.");
                }
                else {
                    if(this.protector != this.name) {//under someone else protection so can not unprotect
                        System.out.println(target.name + " is already under " + protector + "'s protection");//Bug here
                    }
                    else {//to unprotect
                        target.protection = false;
                        System.out.println(target.name + " is no longer under " + this.name + "'s protection");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Target is already dead.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the other child (Villian) class:

```
public class Villian extends SuperPerson{
    int attack(Person target) {
        if(target.type.equals(this.type)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid target!");
            return 0 ;
        }
        else {
            if(target.protection == true) {
                System.out.println("The target is under " + protector + "'s protection"); //Bug here
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return super.attack(target);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Problems like this are more likely to be solved if they include a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
h1.protect(c3);
```

you are storing in `c3` that it is now protected.

However, you are storing the name of the protector not in `c3` but in `h1`:

```
                this.protector = this.name;
```

That means that when you later call

```
h2.protect(c3);
```

the `h2` can read that `c3` is protected, but it cannot read who is protecting `c3`.

To fix this you need to make the field `String protector;` an instance field of the `Person` class and store the name of the protector there:

```
public class Person {
    boolean protection;
    String protector;
}
```

and

```
public class Hero extends SuperPerson {
    void protect(Person target) {
        if(target.type.equals("Super Villian")) {
            System.out.println("You can not protect a villian!");
        } else {
            if (target.health != 0) {
                if (!target.protection) {//to protect
                    target.protection = true;
                    target.protector = this.name;
                    System.out.println(target.name + " is under " + this.protector + "'s proction.");
                } else {
                    if (!target.protector.equals(this.name)) {//under someone else protection so can not unprotect
                        System.out.println(target.name + " is already under " + target.protector + "'s protection");
                    } else {//to unprotect
                        target.protection = false;
                        System.out.println(target.name + " is no longer under " + this.name + "'s protection");
                        target.protector = null;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Target is already dead.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```